# Adding overlay over google maps, leaves bottom part of map showing

Tags: css, google-maps

I am trying to use a google maps location as a background for a page. However, the overlay will not cover the entire map, the bottom of the map will be showing.

Even when I try to set the height of the `map-canvas` and `overlay` to `100vh` the map still exceeds the overlay.

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' + '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD1izGpWuOiZ6HxUdT6HScuSa0oAxdGGj4">
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#map-canvas` does have a different position than `.overlay`, because it's position will be affected by the padding/margin of the page.

You have these options(there may be more):

1. remove the padding/margin:

   ```
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
   }
   ```
2. when you want to preserve the padding/margin and want the overlay to cover the map regardless of the map-size/position, use the `.overlay` as child of `#map-canvas` :

   ```
    <div id="map-canvas"><div class="overlay"></div></div>
   ```

   to make it work you must also set the `noClear`-option of the map to `true` (otherwise the API will remove the `.overlay`)

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    noClear: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' + '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 80%;
  width: 70%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, browsers add a `margin` to the `body`, causing the body to actually take up more than 100% height (100% plus whatever the margin is). Your issue is fixed if you explicitly remove this margin. This is a great example of why CSS resets are popular.

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' + '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD1izGpWuOiZ6HxUdT6HScuSa0oAxdGGj4">
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```